# Error: "param is missing or the value is empty: students"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails. I can't understand what the error is and how to fix it.
Error is **param is missing or the value is empty: students**

form_for helper`

```
    <%= form_for :students, :url=>{:action=>'create'} do |f| %>
```

Strong parameters

```
params.require(:students).permit(:s_name,:batch,:roll_no,:branch,:gender,:date_of_birth,:contact_no_1,:contact_no_2,:email,:spi_1,:spi_2,:spi_3,:spi_4,:spi_5,:spi_6,:spi_7,:cpi_7,:percent_10,:percent_12)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

## students controller

```
def new
  @student = Student.new
end

def create
  @student = Student.new(student_params)
  @student.save
end

def student_params
  params.require(:students).permit(:s_name,:batch,:roll_no,:branch,:gender,:date_of_birth,:contact_no_1,:contact_no_2,:email,:spi_1,:spi_2,:spi_3,:spi_4,:spi_5,:spi_6,:spi_7,:cpi_7,:percent_10,:percent_12)
end
```

## view

```
<% form_for @student do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will inspect the params you'll find that your parameters are not in this form

```
{students: {'s_name': 'xyz', 'batch': 'cse'}}
```

It means the previous answer which was explained by @puneet is the best way to make **CRUD's** Try that way.